# PrimeFaces hotkey Always work with any key

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to create a hot key back to the previous screen by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd>.
I have a hotkey tag

```
<p:hotkey bind="ctrl+shift+b" update="@form" actionListener="#{bean.doBack}" />.
```

But when I press any button, such as : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> , <kbd>Shift</kbd> it always tranfers to previous screen although it isn't the Keystroke I design.
Note: I use PF 4.0

Comment: i don't know where i have to fix ? suggest me pls

Answer (score 0):

i solved this bug by add lib

```
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="hotkey/hotkey.js" target="head"></h:outputScript>
```

It works ok :)